# Next.js Compile error, property undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So there is a indexpage with components, listing ads.

```
const App = ({ads}) => (
  { (ads.items===undefined) ? <></> :  ads.items.map(item => <Ad item={item} key={item.postingId} id={item.postingId}/>) }
)





export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
const res = await fetch(`www.apiadress.com/${queryString.stringify(context.query)}`)
const ads = await res.json()
// console.debug(ads)
console.debug(queryString.stringify(context.query))
return {
  props: {ads}, // will be passed to the page component as props
}
}
```

and component Ad receives those props, and renders cards

```
const Ad = props => (

    <Card className="customCard">
        <Card.Body>
            <Card.Text className="text">          
                <div className="mainDetails">
                <h1 className="ad_Title"><Link href="[ad]" as={props.item.postingId}>{props.item.title}</Link></h1>
                    <p>posted on: {props.item.postingDate.day} / {props.item.postingDate.month}
                    {props.item.postingDate.year}   by {props.item.employer} 
                    </p>

             
                    
                    <div className="description">
                        <p><span><Cash /><b> {props.item.rateFrom}- {props.item.rateTo}  per hour </b></span>     <GeoAlt /> <b>{props.item.city}</b></p>
                        <p> <Clock />  <b>{props.item.jobType}</b></p>  
                    </div>    
                   
                    <p>{props.item.description.slice(0, 230)}.....</p>
                   
                </div>            
          

                <div>
                    <img src={props.item.employerLogoUrl} alt={props.item.employer} className="empImg" />
                    <Button variant="primary" href=""> <Heart width="12" height="12"/>  SHORLIST  </Button>
                </div>

            </Card.Text>

        </Card.Body>
    </Card>



export default Ad;
```

with NPM run dev - everything works perfectly but at NPM run build I am getting an error

> Error occurred prerendering page "/componenets/ad/ad". Read more:
> https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'postingId' of undefined

1. What's causing this? I am assuming that components does not have data before render.
2. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `props.item` is empty on cards component.
2. Add validation check in the start of the Ad component:

```
    if (!props.item) {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I am wondering how `props.item` could be empty though. `Ad` component receives `item` as `props` passed from `App` component which uses `Array.map` method. `Array.map` does not loop through `undefined` values in "holed" arrays, e.g. `[1, undefined, 3]` - in this case `Array.map` would iterate 2 times. Also, `undefined` is not an allowed `JSON` value, so `res.json()` would not produce empty elements. Cheers!

Comment: why it works without problems on NPM RUN DEV? I dont get that error there

Answer (score 2):

it simply that you have some items in your array null so it caused that error. I suggest to rewrite like this so it can avoid unnecessary error

```
const App = ({ads}) => 
   (ads.items || []).map(item => item ? <Ad item={item} key={item.postingId} id={item.postingId}/> : null)
```

Comment: If one of the items was `null` then the error would be: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'postingId' of null`, whereas the OP's error states `undefined`